# How to create additional accordion ( collapse )

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, accordion

1)I have an input .
2)Have collapse ( accordion ) block.

Me skills in js very low. Can anyone help me?

Accordion must appears when in input something typed ( for examlpe ) 10 symbols.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your question">

<!-- This block must appears -->
        <div class="advanced-search" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">         
            <div class="p-heading">
                <h4 class="title-panel panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                     <!-- no title cuz action must appear this block --> <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                </h4>
            </div>      
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">              
                <div class="ct-row ct-col-two">
                    <span class="col-1"><div class="ct-star">*</div><div class="ct-title">what job?</div></span>
                    <span class="col-2">
                        <div class="btn-group-horizontal">
                            <div class="ck-button left">
                                <label >
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span class="left">1</span>                                        
                                </label>                        
                            </div>          
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>      
                </div>
            </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need both jquery and bootstrap.  Simply [enable the accordion effect](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage) with:

```
$('.collapse').collapse()
```

**UPDATE**

This javascript will auto-update the panel-title with the input text

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#question').change(function(){
        var text = $(this).val()
        console.log(text)
        $('#collapseOne').collapse({
            toggle: true
        })
        $('#title').append(text)
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2RV7T/1/

Comment: no man)) it have to appear automatically by typing (for example) 10 symbol in input.

Comment: Actually rereading your question, it sounds like you want the accordion to be hidden first.  Here's an updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/2RV7T/2/

Comment: Almost)) But there mustn't be a input text . And it have to appears by typing 10 or more symbols. ( not ny pressing enter )